# Class 'FirebaseFirestoreService' incorrectly implements class 'Firestore' [error TS2720:]

Tags: typescript, firebase, nestjs, firebase-admin

I have an issue when trying to run nest build

```
node_modules/@aginix/nestjs-firebase-admin/dist/services/firebase-admin-firestore.service.d.ts:2:22 - error TS2720: 
Class 'FirebaseFirestoreService' incorrectly implements class 'Firestore'. Did you mean to extend 'Firestore' and 
inherit its members as a subclass?
  Property 'recursiveDelete' is missing in type 'FirebaseFirestoreService' but required in type 'Firestore'.

2 export declare class FirebaseFirestoreService implements FirebaseFirestore.Firestore {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:278:5
    278     recursiveDelete(
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'recursiveDelete' is declared here.

Found 1 error(s).
```

And i have this config for nestjs-firebase-admin , nest core and nest CLI

```
"@aginix/nestjs-firebase-admin": "^2.1.0",
"@nestjs/common": "^7.5.1",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.5.1",
"@nestjs/cli": "^7.5.1",
```

And I tested this on node v12.17.0, v12.18.1 and on latest but no success. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: What is your `firebase-admin` version?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan it is ^9.7.0

Comment: Could you try to change it to `9.4.2` and see. Just a guess, not sure

Comment: @ErangaHeshan i tested no help, in fact i have tested even 9.1.1